# How to handle JSON returned from HTTP GET request - Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift

This is my code :

```
        let myUrl = NSURL(string:"hostname/file.php");

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET";


    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
            {



                if(error != nil)
                {
                    //Display an alert message

                    return
                }



                do {
                    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                    if let parseJSON = json { /* when the app reach here , will enter the catch and get out */

                        let userId = parseJSON["id"] as? String
                        print(userId)

                        if(userId != nil) 
                        {

                            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(parseJSON["id"], forKey: "id")
                            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(parseJSON["name"], forKey: "name")

                            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()


                        } else {
                            // display an alert message
                                print("error")

                        }

                    }
                } catch
                {
                    print(error)
                }


        }



    }).resume()
```

my app getting the JSON from php file that parse the array from database into JSON and return it using `echo` and it return the following 2 rows :

```
[{"id":"1","name":"CIT","adminstrator_id":"1"},{"id":"2","name":"HelpDesk","adminstrator_id":"1"}]
```

When I print description of `json` I get `nil`

I tried to cast the `json` to `NSArray` , when I print first `json[0]` I get the first row which is good but when I tried to cast result of  `json[0]` to NSDictionary still I'll get nil from it

when the app reach the if statement `if let parseJSON = json` it will enter the catch and it's not printing any error , I don't know why  ?

this my php code :

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "mydb";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM department";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$rows = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($r = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    $conn->close();
    echo json_encode($rows);
} else {
    $conn->close();
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

So is the problem in my request or with handling the request ?

Comment: Could you print data (transformed into String)? Is `json` meant to be a NSDictionary or a NSArray?

Comment: @Larme actually it's nil I just print it , and yes meant to be a NSDictionary

Comment: @Larme the JSON return multiple rows from DB , couldn't be the problem ?

Comment: The JSON is doubtless an array (represented by the square brackets)

Comment: The thing is that your JSON is valid, and `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data:options:)` works, but the cast `as? NSDictionary` won't work since it's a `NSArray` at top level.

Comment: @Zizoo the response is a Array<Dictionary<String,Anyobject>>

Comment: @Larme Ok I get that know but how to manipulate the array cells ? because every cell in the array contain 3 different details

Comment: @larme Thank you , I get it know , thanks for replay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON is an array of `[String:String]` dictionaries.

In a JSON string `[]` represents an array and `{}` represents a dictionary.

An URLRequest is not needed because `GET` is the default mode. `.MutableContainers` is not needed either because the values are only read.

Consider that the JSON returns multiple records. This code just prints all values for `id` and `name`.

```
let myUrl = NSURL(string:"hostname/file.php")!
NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(myUrl) { (data, response, error) in
  if error != nil {
    print(error!)
  } else {
    do {
      if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [[String:String]] {
        for entry in json {
          if let userId = entry["id"], name = entry["name"] {
            print(userId, name)
          }
        }
      } else {
        print("JSON is not an array of dictionaries")
      }
    } catch let error as NSError {
      print(error)
    }
  }
}.resume()
```

Comment: Thank you , that's what I need because I'm not familiar with HTTP requests using swift